# Print the concatenation of the digits of two numbers in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, concatenation

Is there a way to concat numbers in Python, lets say I have the code

```
print(2, 1)
```

I want it to print `21`, not `2 1`and if i use "+", it prints 3. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Changed title from "Concatenation in python"; this should not be construed as the person asking about anything digit-related.

Comment: Tagging `python-3`, since you're cleary on it if your output is `2 1` and not `(2, 1)`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could perhaps convert the integers to strings:

```
print(str(2)+str(1))
```

Answer (score 10):

Use the string formatting operator:

```
print "%d%d" % (2, 1)
```

EDIT: In Python 2.6+, you can also use the format() method of a string:

```
print("{0}{1}".format(2, 1))
```

Comment: The OP is clearly using `python-3`, meaning that `%` is deprecated.

Comment: `%` has not been deprecated. The plan was to do so in Python 3.1, but they did not. You can still use it in 3.2 without any warnings whatsoever.

Comment: str.format is actually available in python 2.6+, not just python3+

Answer (score 8):

You can change the separator used by the print function:

```
print(2, 1, sep="")
```

If you're using python2.x, you can use

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

at the top of the file.

Answer (score 6):

If you have a lot of digits use [`str.join()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) + [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#map):

```
print(''.join(map(str, [2,1])))
```

Otherwise why not simply do:

```
print(2*10+1)
```

Answer (score 5):

This is because 2 and 1 are integers, not strings. In general if you want to do this in *any context besides printing*, you'd have to convert them to strings first. For example:

```
myNumber1 = ...
myNumber2 = ...
myCombinedNumberString = str(myNumber1)+str(myNumber2)
```

In the context of printing, you'd much rather do what Rafael suggests in his answers (string format operator). I'd personally do it like:

```
print( '{}{}'.format(2,1) )
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use python 3.x or 2.7, use [format](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#format)

```
print("{0}{1}".format(2, 1))
```

Comment: 2.6+, actually: http://docs.python.org/release/2.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.format

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import sys
>>> values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> for value in values:
        sys.stdout.write(str(value))
12345
```

Answer (score 0):

If we do not want to convert it into a string.

val = [1,2,3,4]
reduce(lambda x,y: x*10+y, val)

or after getting the result. convert it back to Integer.

Answer (score 0):

`print(f'{2}{1}')` 
gives

```
21

[Program finished]
```

The format used by OP.
It's `<class 'str'>`

Answer (score -1):

Simply use

```
c="2"+"1"
print(c)
```

It will give you `21`.